# Issue with Correlation using Gatling Performance Testing tool

Tags: correlation, gatling

I am new to Gatling
From last 5 days, I am trying to capture below request but I am unable to correlate the below **"sesskey"** which will be used in throughout my whole flow :

```
.feed(feeder)

    .exec(http("request_2")
        .post("/login/index.php")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("username", "${username}")
        .formParam("password", "${password}")
        .formParam("anchor", "")
        .resources(http("request_3")
        .get("/theme/image.php/clean/core/1468244430/t/block_to_dock"),
        http("request_4")

    .get("/lib/javascript.php/1468244430/blocks/course_overview/module.js"),
        http("request_5")
        .get("/theme/image.php/clean/core/1468244430/t/collapsed"),
        http("request_6")
        .get("/theme/image.php/clean/core/1468244430/t/expanded"),
        http("request_7")
        .get("/lib/requirejs.php/1468244430/core/first.js"),
        http("request_8")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?3.17.2/anim-base/anim-base.js&3.17.2/anim-color/anim-color.js&3.17.2/anim-xy/anim-xy.js&3.17.2/anim-curve/anim-curve.js&3.17.2/anim-easing/anim-easing.js&3.17.2/anim-node-plugin/anim-node-plugin.js&3.17.2/anim-scroll/anim-scroll.js"),
        http("request_9")
        .get("/lib/javascript.php/1468244430/lib/requirejs/jquery-private.js"),
        http("request_10")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?3.17.2/cssbutton/cssbutton-min.css")
        .headers(headers_10),
        http("request_11")
        .get("/lib/javascript.php/1468244430/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"),
        http("request_12")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?3.17.2/handlebars-base/handlebars-base.js&3.17.2/handlebars-compiler/handlebars-compiler.js&m/1468244430/core/handlebars/handlebars-debug.js&3.17.2/plugin/plugin.js&m/1468244430/core/lockscroll/lockscroll-debug.js&m/1468244430/core/notification/notification-ajaxexception-debug.js&m/1468244430/core/notification/notification-alert-debug.js&m/1468244430/core/notification/notification-exception-debug.js&m/1468244430/core_message/messenger/messenger-debug.js"),
        http("request_13")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?m/1468244430/calendar/info/info.css")
        .headers(headers_10),
        http("request_14")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?m/1468244430/calendar/info/info-debug.js"),
        http("request_15")
        .post("/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey=LuyCPEUwdm")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .body(RawFileBody("MoodleViewPageV01_0015_request.txt")),
        http("request_16")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?m/1468244430/core/formautosubmit/formautosubmit-debug.js"),
        http("request_17")
        .get("/theme/yui_combo.php?3.17.2/event-mousewheel/event-mousewheel.js&3.17.2/event-resize/event-resize.js&3.17.2/event-hover/event-hover.js&3.17.2/event-touch/event-touch.js&3.17.2/event-move/event-move.js&3.17.2/event-flick/event-flick.js&3.17.2/event-valuechange/event-valuechange.js&3.17.2/event-tap/event-tap.js&3.17.2/event-simulate/event-simulate.js&3.17.2/async-queue/async-queue.js&3.17.2/gesture-simulate/gesture-simulate.js&3.17.2/node-event-simulate/node-event-simulate.js&m/1468244430/core/actionmenu/actionmenu-debug.js"),
        http("request_18")
        .get("/theme/image.php/clean/core/1468244430/t/switch_minus"),
        http("request_19")
        .get("/theme/image.php/clean/core/1468244430/t/switch_plus")))
```

In the request above, `Request_15` where you will get `.post("/lib/ajax/service.php?sesskey=LuyCPEUwdm")` and I want to capture sesskey value `LuyCPEUwdm` which will be going to used multiple times during my scenario.

How I should capture that key ?

Please help
Appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Here, When you will going to record the script using recorder, There...You need to select "save & check Response bodies?" option and then go for recording

So after recording completed, Your response will be stored in "..\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.2\user-files\bodies" path

So you can compare the scenario of your script with the response body files and correlate that value based on captured value in the response body files